# Css not loading in the frontend for Wordpress for any of the themes

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have installed WordPress in an Nginx server. Everything works fine except the css. It doesn't work for any of the themes. The css for wp admin panel looks just fine. Its just the actual website that's not loading. The website in question is zourcecode.info

I can see a list of

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

in my console. Not sure why the server is not able to found just the css for frontend with any theme.

Please help me to load the css on my site. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, first things first, since it can be everything. Are the files present in that structure? If so, does the folder have the right rigths, more important all files to have the right rights to be accessed. What I can see is that every style sheet is being ignored and every js file on front end base, so its not only your theme. It also gives an error on the wp-includes, then, have you installed wp in a subfolder but not specified it in for example the htacess? (ahh read ngnix) check link from @SamvelAleqsanyan

Comment: this link can be useful for you [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx)